# How to get today's, tomorrow's and yesterday's dates on javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get the current date and tomorrow's date and yesteday's date as well in this format `2015-05-21`

I've made these functions which work pretty good, but I wanna get your perspective about that, i'm not really expert in javascript, so I want to make sure that will work properly on my application.

```
function gettodaydate() {
var d = new Date(); 
var date=""+d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getDate();
return date;        
}

 function gettomorrowdate() {
var d = new Date(); 
var date=""+d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+(d.getDate()+1);
return date;        
}

 function getyesterdaydate() {
var d = new Date(); 
var date=""+d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+(d.getDate()-1);
return date;        
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want someone to review your code and suggest best approaches. If that's so, you need to post your question on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Before this got marked as a duplicate, I wrote a quick little script. View this fiddle if you want. It allows you to set the amount of days forward and backward you want to go. http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/94out9dx/

Comment: Also, as an added note, although the marked as duplicate post deals with adding dates to the current date, @YasserB. 's question deals with adding and removing dates and the question was not how to do so, but how to improve upon it if there was a better method. These are clearly 2 different questions that simply overlap in ideas

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks for your comments and for your Jsfiddle code, it really helps, I just wanted to make sure that my code works fine, and I want to undestand more how we can play with dates in Javascript. thanks again

Comment: @YasserB. Just to let you know, I updated my code to fix some issues. The code now works in terms of time instead of date (prevents negative dates from showing up) and also adds a leading zero if the date's number is less than 10

Answer (score 14):

Today's

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

Print:

```
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
```

Then... if a day has 24 hours >> 60 minutes 60 seconds 1000 milliseconds....

```
var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I think this is far too complex. Something you'll look back on and say: "what does this code do?"

Comment: @Steven because of that's why programmers do we have variable names and comments...

Comment: True, but why go the way of detracting 24 hours, and multiplying by 60, 60, 60 and 1000 if you can simply do d.getDate() - 1 ? This is maybe something to do with personal preference. Anyways, I was just commenting. I didn't downvote your suggestion or anything because it clearly will work.

Comment: "I think this is far too complex."  Go and have a look at how painful it is to write this simple code in Xcode...  Now that's a masterclass in "complex" !!   ;-)